# OpenLayers - how to create 2 different colors from one color?

Tags: openlayers, color

So I am using `asArray()` to create rgba color from color provided as a string. I noticed a very strange behaviour when I create two colors from same orginal string. It seems like they both reference same object.

Take a look at this:

```
const color = 'red';

const fillColor = asArray(color);
const strokeColor = asArray(color);

fillColor[3] = 0.05;
strokeColor[3] = 0.2;

console.log(fillColor);
console.log(strokeColor);
```

Expected output:

```
[255, 0, 0, 0.05]
[255, 0, 0, 0.2]
```

Actual output:

```
[255, 0, 0, 0.2]
[255, 0, 0, 0.2]
```

So it seems these colors are somehow bound and changing one changes another.
What I tried is to deep copy a string like this:

```
const fillColor = asArray(color.repeat(1));
const strokeColor = asArray(color.repeat(1));
```

But it still acts the same.

How do I create different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the the [openlayers documentation for the asArray function](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_color.html), it says that the results get cached. So your two results are indeed referring to the same object and should not be edited.

If you want to edit the colors afterwards, I would do something like:

```js
const fillColor = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(asArray(color)));
const strokeColor = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(asArray(color));

fillColor[3] = 0.05;
strokeColor[3] = 0.2;
```

Which should solve your problem.

Comment: Simpler would be `const fillColor = asArray(color).slice()`.